# I want to sort file names in array as in windows folder order by name

Tags: php, sorting, directory, filenames

How do I sort a file name in an array, like in a windows folder, by name? The code and array are just like this:

```
$arr =  array('php__01.png','php__02.png','php__03.png','php_2_01.png','php_2_02.png','php_10_01.png','php_10_02.png','php_9_02.png','php_9_01.png','php_9_03.png');
```

---

```
<?php
$arr =  array('php__01.png','php__02.png','php__03.png','php_2_01.png','php_2_02.png','php_10_01.png','php_10_02.png','php_9_02.png','php_9_01.png','php_9_03.png');
function cmp($a, $b) {
    $a_temp = str_replace('_', '', $a);
    $b_temp = str_replace('_', '', $b);     
    return strcmp($a_temp,$b_temp);
}
usort($arr, "cmp");
?>
```

export like this:

```
array(10) {
[0]=>
string(11) "php__01.png"
[1]=>
string(11) "php__02.png"
[2]=>
string(11) "php__03.png"
[3]=>
string(13) "php_10_01.png"
[4]=>
string(13) "php_10_02.png"
[5]=>
string(12) "php_2_01.png"
[6]=>
string(12) "php_2_02.png"
[7]=>
string(12) "php_9_01.png"
[8]=>
string(12) "php_9_02.png"
[9]=>
string(12) "php_9_03.png"
}
```

and I want to sort like that:

```
array(10) {
[0]=>
string(10) "py__01.png"
[1]=>
string(10) "py__02.png"
[2]=>
string(10) "py__03.png"
[3]=>
string(11) "py_2_01.png"
[4]=>
string(11) "py_2_02.png"
[5]=>
string(11) "py_9_01.png"
[6]=>
string(11) "py_9_02.png"
[7]=>
string(11) "py_9_03.png"
[8]=>
string(12) "py_10_01.png"
[9]=>
string(12) "py_10_02.png"
}
```

Comment: Try not removing "_" char before sortening

Comment: You need the natural ordering...[func_array_natsort](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_natsort.asp)

Comment: @ComputerPhysicsLab I had tested and the result is not my need;

Comment: @FrayneKonokI tested many times, but that is the wrong result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is the solution:

```
<?php
$arr =  array('php__01.png','php__02.png','php__03.png','php_2_01.png','php_2_02.png','php_10_01.png','php_10_02.png','php_9_02.png','php_9_01.png','php_9_03.png');
function reduce($a) {
    $a = str_replace('_', '-', $a);
    $a = preg_replace('#([0-9]+)#e', 'sprintf("%02d", "\\1")', $a);

    return $a;
}
function cmp($a, $b) {
    $a_temp = reduce($a);
    $b_temp = reduce($b);

    return strcmp($a_temp,$b_temp);
}
usort($arr, "cmp");
print_r($arr);
?>
```

http://ideone.com/Yt6jpQ

You need to replace "_" by "-" because "-" char comes first when ordering numbers.

And you need also to pad numbers with leading zeros, that's the reason of preg_match and sprintf.

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => php__01.png
    [1] => php__02.png
    [2] => php__03.png
    [3] => php_2_01.png
    [4] => php_2_02.png
    [5] => php_9_01.png
    [6] => php_9_02.png
    [7] => php_9_03.png
    [8] => php_10_01.png
    [9] => php_10_02.png
)
```

Comment: This answer should be updated, as the preg_replace `/e` modifier has been deprecated (see [this RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_preg_replace_eval_modifier)), and since PHP 7 it is not longer supported and produces a warning (see [PHP 7.0 - Changed functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.changed-functions.php)).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom sorting function using [usort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php); in this case, to sort by each element of the filename in turn

```
$cb = function($valueA, $valueB) {
    $vA = explode('_', $valueA);
    $vB = explode('_', $valueB);
    $element = 0;
    do {
        $x = (int) $vA[$element] - (int) $vB[$element++];
    } while ($x == 0);
    return $x;
};

usort($arr, $cb);
```

Comment: I tested and get the result ,but not right.array(10) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "php__01.png"
  [1]=>
  string(11) "php__02.png"
  [2]=>
  string(11) "php__03.png"
  [3]=>
  string(13) "php_10_01.png"
  [4]=>
  string(13) "php_10_02.png"
  [5]=>
  string(12) "php_2_01.png"
  [6]=>
  string(12) "php_2_02.png"
  [7]=>
  string(12) "php_9_01.png"
  [8]=>
  string(12) "php_9_02.png"
  [9]=>
  string(12) "php_9_03.png"
}

Comment: Modified, I was comparing as a string (like your original using strcmp()) rather than numerically

Comment: thanks.Computer Physics Lab's code is worked,and the result is needed;

Comment: I'm sorry.I tested and found that your code is also I nedd.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more generic approach that does not split at `"_"`.

```
$arr =  array('php__01.png','php__02.png','php__03.png','php_2_01.png','php_2_02.png','php_10_01.png','php_10_02.png','php_9_02.png','php_9_01.png','php_9_03.png');

$wincmp = function ($a, $b) {
    $a = str_replace('_', '', $a);
    $b = str_replace('_', '', $b);
    $a_arr = preg_split("#([0-9]+)#", $a, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    $b_arr = preg_split("#([0-9]+)#", $b, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    
    $a_arr_len = count($a_arr);
    $b_arr_len = count($b_arr);
    
    $min_len = min($a_arr_len, $b_arr_len);
    
    for($i=0; $i<$min_len; $i++)
    {
        if (is_numeric($a_arr[$i]) && is_numeric($b_arr[$i]))
            $cmp = gmp_sign((int) $a_arr[$i] - (int) $b_arr[$i]);
        else
            $cmp = strcmp($a_arr[$i],$b_arr[$i]);
        if($cmp != 0)
            return $cmp;
    }
    
    if($a_arr_len < $b_arr_len)
        return -1;
    elseif($a_arr_len > $b_arr_len)
        return 1;
    
    return 0;
};

usort($arr, $wincmp);
print_r($arr);
```